# Dynamic body class with Angular UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to find an elegant way to have a custom dynamically class of the **body tag** that I can set easily from the `ui-router configurations` and if none is set, I can use a default option or none.

**Example:**

***routes.js***

```
$stateProvider
      .state('login', {
           url: "/login",
           template: 'Login'
      })
      .state('register', {
           url: "/register",
           template: 'Register'
      }).
      .state('profile', {
           url: "/profile",
           template: 'Profile'
      });;
```

***Simple markup HTML***

```
<html>
   <body class=""> <!-- Dynamically class to change -->
      <div ui-view></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

***Scenario:***

1 - Visiting the `state` **login** I should have the **class** of the body equals to `auth`

2 - Visiting the `state` **register** at this point it will have the same `auth` class

3 - Visiting the `state` **profile** the body will have the **default** class or **none**

How do you achieve that?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can have a master AppController that controls this:

```
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController as appController">
...
<body class="{{ appController.bodyClasses }}">
```

Inside AppController:

```
var vm = this;
vm.bodyClasses = 'default';

// this'll be called on every state change in the app
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    if (angular.isDefined(toState.data.bodyClasses)) {
        vm.bodyClasses = toState.data.bodyClasses;
        return;
    }

    vm.bodyClasses = 'default';
});
```

Inside your route defs:

```
  .state('register', {
       url: "/register",
       template: 'Register',
       data: {
           bodyClasses: 'auth'
       }
  });
```

See [UI Router documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#attach-custom-data-to-state-objects) for more on this data-attribute strategy.

Comment: This is a really eloquent solution to this. Nicely done!

Comment: For those coming to this answer, take a look at @JeremyWeir's answer, which utilizes a directive instead. Either answer will work, but his is more robust and elegant overall.

Answer (score 27):

Here's a similar approach as @jmq's using state data, but implemented as a directive instead of a controller. (The nice thing about the directive is you can apply this to any arbitrary elements)

**Example Markup**

```
<body ng-app="app" route-css-classnames>
```

**Routes Config (routes.js)**

```
$stateProvider
  .state('login', {
       url: "/login",
       template: 'Login',
       data : {
           cssClassnames : 'auth'
       }
  })
  .state('register', {
       url: "/register",
       template: 'Register',
       data : {
           cssClassnames : 'auth'
       }
  }).
  .state('profile', {
       url: "/profile",
       template: 'Profile'
  });
```

**Directive (routeCssClassnames.js)**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('shared').directive('routeCssClassnames', routeCssClassnames);

    function routeCssClassnames($rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {},
            link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

                $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                    var fromClassnames = angular.isDefined(fromState.data) && angular.isDefined(fromState.data.cssClassnames) ? fromState.data.cssClassnames : null;
                    var toClassnames = angular.isDefined(toState.data) && angular.isDefined(toState.data.cssClassnames) ? toState.data.cssClassnames : null;

                    // don't do anything if they are the same
                    if (fromClassnames != toClassnames) {
                        if (fromClassnames) {
                            elem.removeClass(fromClassnames);
                        }

                        if (toClassnames) {
                            elem.addClass(toClassnames);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}());
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Directives should be used when there is a need to modify an element.

Comment: Shouldn't "$rootScope" in the link function be "scope"? Otherwise, in my case it threw me an error.

Comment: best solution here

Answer (score 1):

You could also apply this on your body tag or wherever you need it.

```
ng-class="$state.current.name"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a version of @JeremyWeir's directive using ui-router@1.x transition hooks.

```
import angular from 'angular';

class RouteCssClassNamesDirective {
  constructor($transitions) {
    this.$transitions = $transitions;
    this.restrict = 'A';
  }

  link(scope, element, attrs) {
    this.$transitions.onSuccess({}, (trans) => {
      const fromClassNames = angular.isDefined(trans.from().data) && angular.isDefined(trans.from().data.cssClassNames) ? trans.from().data.cssClassNames : null;
      const toClassNames = angular.isDefined(trans.to().data) && angular.isDefined(trans.to().data.cssClassNames) ? trans.to().data.cssClassNames : null;
      if (fromClassNames !== toClassNames) {
        if (fromClassNames) {
          element.removeClass(fromClassNames);
        }
        if (toClassNames) {
          element.addClass(toClassNames);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  static create() {
    return new RouteCssClassNamesDirective(...arguments);
  }

}

RouteCssClassNamesDirective.create.$inject = ['$transitions'];

export default angular.module('shared')
  .directive('routeCssClassNames', RouteCssClassNamesDirective.create);
```