# [AngularJS]: Change body class according to state

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to change the body class according to the current state on AngularJS.

E.g. if *state1*, then `body class="blue"`;
if *state2*, then `body class="red"`;

I have two states:

```
.state('app.state1', {
      url: "/state1",
      data: {
        class: blue
      },
      templateUrl: "state1.html",
      controller: "MyCtrl"
    })
    .state('app.state2', {
      url: "/state2",
      data: {
        class: red
      },
      templateUrl: "state2.html",
      controller: "MyCtrl"
    });
```

Then, inside the `index.html`:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

Any ideas about how to do this?

**This answer solves the question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32574746**

Comment: I've tried that but I didn't manage to make it work for my case. It's not recognizing the `{{ appController.bodyClasses }}`

Comment: Have you tried to set the `ng-app` directive on the `<html>` tag rather than on the `<body>`?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work either. I get this output: `<body class>`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ng-class`, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

```
<body ng-class="{red: x==='red', blue: x==='blue'}">
   ...
</body>
```

Comment: Does this work with states? I tried here but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the ui-sref-active directive.

In order to make the class active to your element when the ui-router state matches use the following:

ui-sref-active="active"

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active

Comment: This is okay if I have only two states (active and non-active), right? But how could I use this with more states (four, for example)?

Comment: E.g. if I want four states to have four different body classes (blue, red, green, yellow). Then, I can't use the ui-sref-active directive, right?